# selecting from couchdb in nodejs craddle?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, express

I have couchdb and document my_users whitch looks like:

```
_id
password
email
...
```

how can I select _id  for _id and password. 
I would like sth like mysql `select _id from my_users where _id = "mylogin" and password = "mypassword"`

i using cradle

and trying sth like this:

```
db.save('_design/user', {
    views: {
       byUsername: {
          map: 'function (doc) { if (doc.resource === "my_users") { emit(doc._id) } }'
              }
            }
          });   


this.db.view('user/byUsername', { key: 'myuser' }, function (err, doc) {       

              console.dir(doc);   ///this is empty array :|
          });
```

but it doesn;t work correctly how to use it ??

Comment: Have you tried to query your view with curl to ensure that it actually works. Then try to use the `include_docs` option or to emit document in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit both the `_id` and `password` together.

```
function(doc) {
  var key;
  if(doc.resource == "my_users") {
    key = [doc._id, doc.password];
    emit(key, null);
  }
}
```

To find a username/password match, search for the same key.

```
var username = 'myuser';
var password = 'secret';
var key = [username, password];
this.db.view('users/byUsernamePassword', {"key":key}, function(err, doc) {
  console.log("Result:");
  console.dir({"err":err, "doc":doc});
})
```